# Formally prove: $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L_1\Longrightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+k}=L_1,\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: analysis

OK, so I'm given the following:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L_1\iff\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N(\epsilon)\in\mathbb{N}\ni\forall n>N(\epsilon),\ \left|x_n-L_1\right|<\epsilon$$

I just have no idea how to use that to prove

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+k}=L_1\iff\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N(\epsilon)\in\mathbb{N}\ni\forall n>N(\epsilon),\ \left|x_{n+k}-L_1\right|<\epsilon$$

What can I possibly do with $\left|x_{n+k}-L_1\right|$ to make it so I can make use of the given information?

Comment: Can you define a new sequence $y_n = x_{n+k}$?

Comment: @Tunococ Yes? I guess? But I still don't see how that gets me anywhere.

Comment: From what you are given, are you allowed to replace the symbol "$x$" with something else?

Comment: I don't see why not...

Comment: So if I replace "$x$" by "$y$" in the first statement, and if I define $y_n = x_{n+k}$, I believe I get the second statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know 
$$\forall\varepsilon>0\;\exists N(\varepsilon)\in\mathbb{N}\;\forall n>N(\varepsilon)\ \left|x_n-L_1\right|<\varepsilon$$
and want to prove
$$\forall\varepsilon>0\;\exists N'(\varepsilon)\in\mathbb{N}\;\forall n>N'(\varepsilon)\ \left|x_{n+k}-L_1\right|<\varepsilon$$
Just set $N'(\varepsilon)=N(\varepsilon) - k$. If $n>N'(\varepsilon)$ then $n+k > N'(\varepsilon)+k=N(\varepsilon)$ and you can use the first statement.

Comment: I do believe that helps quite a bit. I think I may see a general tactic now for proving these general theorems as opposed to proving a specific limit exists.

Comment: I just thought of something - How do I know that $x_{n+k}<x_n$? I want to say $\left|x_{n+k}-L\right|\leq\left|x_{N_{2}(\epsilon)+k}-L\right|=\left|x_{N_{1}(\epsilon)}-L\right|<\epsilon$ but it feels like I can't jump to that conclusion somehow.

Comment: You just need that $|x_{n+k}-L_1|<\varepsilon$ which follows from $n+k>N(\varepsilon)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here we know that $<x_n> \rightarrow L_1$. So ($\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists N \in \aleph)$ s.t $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$. Now take $m=n+k$ so $m>n>\aleph \rightarrow |x_m-L|<\epsilon$ (for all $k$) this is true.